# Rails, Globalize3 check if translated attributes changed?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, globalize3

In Rails we can check if a model attribute is changed, using `obj.field_changed?`.

Say I have a model that uses `Globalize3`.

It has `translates :name`

How can I check if the name attribute got changed?

Something like `obj.name_changed?`

Comment: please explain more carefully, when does it changed on the same request or could be changed an hour ago?

Comment: definitely on the same request

Comment: There was an issue about this in the Globalize gem but it was closed: https://github.com/globalize/globalize/issues/690

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got the solution. I am posting it as an answer considering someone might get benefited.

To check if the translated attributes got changed, just need to open `Translation class` provided by `Globalize3` inside the corresponding model class.

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  translates :name
  .......
# Open the Translation class
  class Translation
    after_save do #you may define a private method as callback method
      if name_changed?
        #accomplish your tasks...
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 5):

I am not sure that the proposed answer would really give you the expected results.

Say you have

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  translates :name
end
```

If you instantiate a post:

```
p = Post.last
```

check its name:

```
p.name
=> "My old name"
```

and change the name:

```
p.name = "My new name"
```

If you do:

```
p.name_changed?
```

you will get a no method error.

If, as you propose, you call the Translation class from within the model:

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  translates :name
  .......
  # Open the Translation class
  class Translation
    after_save do #you may define a private method as callback method
      if name_changed?
      #accomplish your tasks...
      end
    end
  end
end
```

You will only be able to know if your attribute has changed after you have saved your main translatable record. This might not be what you want (imagine for example that you want to generate a new slug, based on the new name of the post each time it changes, you would then have to save your post a second time).

Instead of calling the class from within the method, you could also try (before saving your post) a:

```
p.translation.name_changed?
=> false
```

The result will be a false. This can be explained. If, after having changed the name with a:

```
p.name = "My new name"
=> "My new name"
```

p.translation.name will return:

```
p.translation.name
=> "My old name"
```

This is because Globalize stores the translated attributes in virtual attributes of the instantiated translatable model.

You could do:

```
p.translation.name = "My new name"
=> "My new name"
```

then:

```
p.translation.name_changed?
=> true
```

However, you lose part of the benefit of using Globalize.

What I do is that, in the Post model, I override the getter and setter for the virtual attribute I am interested in:

```
def name
  translation.name
end

def name=(val)
  translation.name = val
end
```

Now, if I do:

```
p.name
=> "My old name"
p.name = "My new name"
=> "My new name"
p.name_changed?
# no method error
p.translation.name_changed?
=> true
p.translation.name
=> "My new name"
```

and this, before saving the post.

Comment: This helped explain a lot, thank you for this detailed explanation!